# How can I use JSX syntax in Vue 2.7 setup?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, jsx

```html
<template>
  <base-table :data="dataList" :table-config="tableConfig" ></base-table>
</template>

<script lang="tsx" setup>
const buttonDetail = (row) => {
  console.log(row);
};

const tableConfig: Array<TableColumnConfig> = [
  { label: '退出原因', prop: 'reason' },
  { label: '主体总数', prop: 'count' },
  { label: '总数占比（占名单总数）', prop: 'percent' },
  {
    label: '操作',
    render: (row) => {
      return (
        <span>
          <el-button type="text" onClick={buttonDetail(row)}>
            查看详情
          </el-button>
        </span>
      );
    },
  },
];

const dataList = ref<Array<any>>([
  {
    reason: '原因',
    count: 1,
    percent: '80%',
  },
]);

</script>
```

In Vue2.7 with vite3.0
I made a custom table component. It was rendered by an Object with JSX element.
But events was not supported. It seems like that the setup hook is not expose $listener.
How to solve that?

Comment: Hi, can you please give a try to that one? https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#JSX

Answer (score 0):

```
//...
    render: (row) => {
      return (
        <span>
          <el-button type="text" {...{...{on:()=>{buttonClick(row)}}}}>
            查看详情
          </el-button>
        </span>
      );
    },
//...
```

This one can transform event.